# pandas difference between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the day difference between today, and dates in my dataframe.

Below is my conversion of dates in my dataframe

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Below is my code to get today

```
today1=dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today1=pd.to_datetime(today1)
```

Both are converted to pandas.to_datetime, but when I do subtraction, the below error came out.

> ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.

Can someone help to advise? Thanks!

Comment: What line produces the error? How do you perform the subtraction?

Comment: works fine for me.  check the types/dtypes to make sure you have what you think you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example how you can do this:

```
import pandas
import datetime as dt
```

First, you have to get today.

```
today1=dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today1=pd.to_datetime(today1)
```

Then, you can construct the data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Date':'2016-11-24 11:03:10.050000', 'today1': today1 }, index = [0])
```

In this example I just have 2 columns, each with one value.

Next, you should check the data types:

```
print(df.dtypes)
Date      datetime64[ns]
today1    datetime64[ns]
```

If both data types are `datetime64[ns]`, you can then subtract `df.Date` from `df.today1`.

```
print(df.today1 - df.Date)
```

The output:

```
0   19 days 12:56:49.950000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```